# user login not works

Tags: php, laravel

we have fresh Laravel project with authentication using:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

our default login form is working fine in 'login.blade.php' view.

but we have separate forms in our 'welcome.blade.php' view that created using mdbootstrap. welcome page login form not working. following code is form and inputs tag. why not working?

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="md-form">
        <input type="email" id="materialLoginFormEmail" name="email">
        <label for="materialLoginFormEmail">E-mail</label>
    </div>                  
    <div class="md-form">
        <input type="password" id="materialLoginFormPassword" name="password">
        <label for="materialLoginFormPassword">Password</label>
    </div>

    <!-- Sign in button -->
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block my-4 waves-effect z-depth-0" type="submit">
        {{ __('Login') }}
    </button>
    …
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have any error log or output ?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you get an error? Doesn't the user get logged in?

Comment: form do nothing. no refresh no message and user not be logged in.

Comment: when we delete 'name' attrs of input tags, then output is error code 419. but now our 'name's are correct! is not?

Comment: Are you using JS to post the form, like Ajax or similar? If yes, show that code and check the console log. I have to ask, does your HTML actually look like this or is it reformatted for SO?

Comment: not that default generated forms by Laravel are working fine and we just copied them (method , action , name attributes)

Comment: are 'id' attributes of input tags correct?

Comment: no I just added mdbootstrap js files in master blade